# Is it possible to catch the "command not found" event?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

I'm using bash, and wondering if it is possible to catch the "-bash: gitb: command not found" event to replace it with your own handler.

For example, I'd like that if I run

`gitb clone` instead of `git clone`, it gets automatically corrected.

It would be possible if I could catch the `command not found` event, check that the command starts with `git` and the first word is 4 characters long (or I might enter any kind of rules in a bash script).

It would also make it possible to automagically create aliases to other commands, without having to create those by hand (or with a loop).

Is they such functionality in bash (I'm using version 4.1) ?
Any other ideas appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a command isn't found, `bash` will execute the function `command_not_found_handle`, if defined. As an example:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    cmd=$1
    shift
    if [[ ${#cmd} -gt 3 && $cmd = git* ]]; then
        git "$@"
    else
        return 127
    fi
}
```

Comment: Looks like I confused `command_not_found_handle` with `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Updating.

Comment: Is it possible to catch an event when a command was found (so that I could also rewrite `git clne` to `git clone` for example ? )

Comment: There is no built-in handler for this; but for `git` in particular you could write a simple wrapper function to correct trivial errors in the subcommand.

Comment: This is what Git aliases are typically used for: `git config --global alias.clne clone`.